# Printing out "undefined" on onPress in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I a new to `React Native` and using youtube to learn from tutorials.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [enteredGoal, setEnteredGoal] = useState('');

  const goalInputHandler = (enteredText) => {
    setEnteredGoal(enteredText);
  }

  const addGoalHandler = () => {
    console.log(enteredGoal);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput placeholder="Course Goals" style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={()=>goalInputHandler()} />
        <Button title="Add" onPress={() => addGoalHandler()}/>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    padding: 50
  },
  inputContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center'
  },
  input: {
    width: '80%', borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1, padding: 10
  }
});
```

`onPress` I am getting `undefined` value. I have created this project using expo.

[image: code error]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I leave an upvote to your post for motivation.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are losing the string in your `onChangeText` because you call `goalInputHandler` without any parameter, so it will always be `undefined`. Could you try this:

```js
<TextInput
  placeholder="Course Goals"
  style={styles.input}
  onChangeText={goalInputHandler}
/>
```

Comment: awesome and fast. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot @HermitCrab :)